# Powering a 14.4V motor - RS550

Tags: power, motor, drill

I took this motor from a cordless drill and I would like to power up directly from a power supply and not from the battery. The [datasheet](http://www.robotstorehk.com/rs_550pcvc.pdf) says the stall current draw is 70/85 Amps (I'm not sure wich model I have).

So do I need an 14.4V power supply capable of giving up to 85 Amps or am I missing something? Is there some kind of a workaround that can be done here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, 85A is the stall-current, ie the current it draws if the motor is prevented from moving if the drill gets stuck or so. During normal load you might expect 10 or maybe 15 amps, but use a fuse if you're uncertain.

I suggest you try an old PC-power supply, many of them can supply about 15-20 amps on their 12V rails (pentium 4 and onwards). 12V will probably be sufficient for you app and they are readily availible and often free.

Good luck!

Comment: I know this a very old post but I'm trying to do exactly this and my power supply stops itself when providing more than 1 amp... Did you manage to have it working?